# How does string interpolation work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, string-interpolation

Does the Kotlin compiler translate `"Hello, $name!"` using something like

```
java.lang.String.format("Hello, %s!", name)
```

or is there some other mechanism?

And if I have a class like this for example:

```
class Client {
  val firstName: String
  val lastName: String
  val fullName: String
    get() = "$firstName $lastName"
}
```

Will this getter return a cached string or will it try to build a new string? Should I use lazyOf delegate instead?

I know that there will be no performance issue unless there will be millions of calls to `fullName`, but I haven't found documentation about this feature except for how to use it.

Comment: Maybe this link can be useful for readers.  http://developine.com/kotlin-idioms-introductory-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Kotlin compiler translates this code to:

```
new StringBuilder().append("Hello, ").append(name).append("!").toString()
```

There is no caching performed: every time you evaluate an expression containing a string template, the resulting string will be built again.

Comment: What will be the syntax if I want something like `val loc: String = "$location.latitude, $location.longitude"` ??

Comment: @BugsHappen I know I'm late, but for future readers: if you need a more complex expression than just a variable name, use braces: `"${location.latitude}, ${location.longitude}"`

Comment: @Joffrey Thank you from the future, I could not find this in the docs.

Answer (score 21):

Regarding your 2nd question:
If you need caching for `fullName`, you may and should do it explicitly:

```
class Client {
    val firstName: String
    val lastName: String
    val fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
}
```

This code is equivalent to your snipped except that the underlying getter `getFullName()` now uses a final private field with the result of concatenation.

Answer (score 13):

Always use curly brackets to avoid surprises. For example if you're string interpolating an object property, you should be enclosing it in curly brackets:

```
print("Your username is ${user.username}\n")
```

Answer (score 11):

As you know, in string interpolation, string literals containing placeholders are evaluated, yielding a result in which placeholders are replaced with their corresponding values.
so interpolation (in KOTLIN) goes this way:

```
var age = 21

println("My Age Is: $age")
```

Remember: "$" sign is used for interpolation.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I think. FYI it seems if you're interpolating a "companion object" (ie property), it needs to be wrapped in brackets as well. EX: `println("My age is: ${person.age}")`

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
String.format("%s %s", client.firstName, client.lastName)
```