# Kotlin extension property is not recognized in string template

Tags: kotlin

I've started to try kotlin out and a question has appeared
I've declared an extension property for a mutable list and tried to use it in the string template this way:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = mutableListOf(1,2,3)
    //  here if use String template the property does not work, list itself is printed
     println("the last index is $list.lastIndex")
    // but this works - calling method
    println("the last element is ${list.last()}")
    // This way also works, so the extension property works correct
    println("the last index is " +list.lastIndex)
}

val <T> List<T>.lastIndex: Int
    get() = size - 1
```

and I've got the following output

```
the last index is [1, 2, 3].lastIndex
the last element is 3
the last index is 2
```

The output of the first println is expected to be the same as the third one. I've tried to get the last element of the list in the template and it worked ok (second output), so is that a bug or I am missing something when using an extension property?

I am using kotlin 1.0.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your template-property in curly braces, just like you did with `list.last()`.

```
println("the last index is ${list.lastIndex}")
```

Without the curly braces, it only recognizes `list` as the template-property.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin compiler needs to interpret the `string` in some way to build a [`StringBuilder` expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442198/how-does-string-interpolation-work-in-kotlin). Since you're using a `.` the expression needs to be wrapped in `${..}` for the compiler to know how to interpret it:

```
println("the last index is ${list.lastIndex}") // the last index is 5
```

The expression:

```
println("the last index is $list.lastIndex")
```

is equivalent to

```
println("the last index is ${list}.lastIndex")
```

Hence you see the `list.toString()` result in console.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! upvoted, accepting the earlier answer